# Set Image source from Image path : Xamarin PCL (Cross Platform)

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am capturing image files using Image picker in Xamarin Forms. I am able to get the image file and its path (e.g. **\storage\emulated\0\test\ABC.jpg** in android).

However, I want to show that image again when user visits that page in my app.

I am not able to render and show the image from that path.

I tried this:

```
   ImgUser.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imgfile1.Path);
```

which didn't work.

Can anyone suggest a way to show Image from the given path on the Image object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your image into a stream and then you can assign it to the image as an Image Source.

```
ImgUser.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
    var stream = imgfile1.GetStream();
    return stream;
});
```

It's working for me and hope this will also work for you.

Comment: This worked for us...!! Thanks. @chandresh-khambhayata